# conevert json date object to milliseconds in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to convert josn date object to milliseconds in angularjs, for instance:

2018-01-13T12:22:06.165Z  to  237891242128

any help will be appriciated.thnaks

Comment: Do you use moment.js

Comment: no, how can i use it ?

Comment: `new Date(2018, 01, 13, 12,22, 06, 165).getTime();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getTime()`

```js
var date = new Date("2018-01-13T12:22:06.165Z");
console.log(date.getTime());
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. the date i give it is not static. here is the sample :                {{product.date_expiration.getTime()}}

Comment: Is `date_expiration` a date or a string ?

Comment: it  is   a date : date_expiration: {type: Date}

Comment: Please show me what is inside `product.date_expiration`

Comment: I got this  :    2018-01-13T12:22:06.165Z

Comment: Ok thus this it not a date but simply a string. Please do like my code snippet `new Date(product.date_expiration)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Javascript Date you can use:

```
var timestampDate = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: it was not a static day it like following : {{produit.date_expiration.getTime()}}

Comment: @Nassim i reccomend always use timestamp in your service.